# sqlite3_exec() fails without error code in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm building a wrapper for the sqlite3 API which lets me collect and format data from a database with a single function call. All my SQL is correct (I checked it using dbBrowser for sqlite) and vscode shows no errors with my code.

The function where my code fails:

```
void sqlWrapper::sqlop_Operator(sqlite3 *db, const char *sql, bool returnData) { 
    int result;
    char *errorMsg = 0; 
    const char* data = "Callback function called";
    
    auto callback = sqlWrapper::sqlop_Callback_Discard;
    if (returnData) {
        callback = sqlWrapper::sqlop_Callback_Return;
    }
    //test:
    std::cout << "before errorMsg\n"; //code stops here unless I remove next line
    std::cout << errorMsg << "\n";
    std::cout << "after errorMsg\n";
    
    result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &errorMsg);
    
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << "Could not complete operation. SQL ERROR: " << errorMsg << "\n"; //program prints up to "SQL ERROR: " then stops
        sqlite3_free(errorMsg);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Successfully completed operation. \n";
    }
      
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "sqlite3/sqlite3.h"
#include "sqlWrapper.hpp"

int main() {   
    sqlite3 *database;
    const char *dbRelativePath = "users/users.db";
    
    sqlWrapper::connect(database, dbRelativePath);
    
    const char *sql = "SELECT * from USERS";  
    std::vector<std::vector<char *> > data = sqlWrapper::sqlop(database, sql, true); 

    if (!data.empty()) {  //display each record   
        for (int I = 0; I<data.size()-1; I++) {
            std::cout << "\n Record: \n";
            std::vector<char *> record = data[I];
            for (int i = 0; i<record.size()-1; i++) {
                std::cout << record[i] << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    sqlWrapper::disconnect(database);

    return 0;
}
```

sqlop():

```
std::vector<std::vector<char *> > sqlWrapper::sqlop(sqlite3 *db, const char *sql, bool returnData) {
    dataReturn.clear();
    std::vector<std::vector<char *> > data;
    sqlop_Operator(db, sql, returnData);
    data = dataReturn;
    dataReturn.clear();
    return data;
}
```

EDIT:
replaced `char * dbRelativePath` with `const char *dbRelativePath`, which fixed the ISO C++ warnings.

EDIT:
Here is the callback function:

```
int sqlWrapper::sqlop_Callback_Return(void *Unused, int colNumber, char **fieldContent, char **colName) {
    std::cout << "callback_return";
    std::vector<char *> record;
    for (int i = 0; i<colNumber-1; i++) {
        record.push_back(fieldContent[i]);
    }
    dataReturn.push_back(record);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the warnings.

Comment: Uh, you have `char *errorMsg = 0; std::cout << errorMsg << "\n";` What good do you expect, printing a null pointer? Note that all this happens before `sqlite3_exec` call - SQLite has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your callback function.

Comment: What does "fail" mean? What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: sqlite3_exec() should call my callback function, which would then ``std::cout << "callback_return", but instead sqlite3_exec() returns an error code to result. When I try to print the error message (which should be in errorMsg), it prints nothing and my program stops running prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm an idiot. Turns out my sqlWrapper::connect() function wasn't properly connecting to the database, despite the response claiming that it was. Everything is working now. Thanks for the help.